# Proof of Riemann's existence theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to find a proof of the existence thm as stated in  Paola Frediani, Alessandro Ghigi and Matteo Penegini's Article: Shimura Varieties In The Torelli Locus Via
Galois Coverings (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0973v2.pdf) and I cannot find one.

The statement is:

A finite group G acts as a group of automorphisms on some
compact Riemann surface C in such a way that C/G ≃ $\mathbb P^1$
if and only if
there are natural numbers $m_1, . . . , m_r$ and an admissible epimorphism
θ : Γ($m_1, . . . , m_r$) → G

The theorem i asked about is theorem 2.3, both the theorem and the definition are at page 5 of the article. I'll add also that I tried to follow the reference on the document which point to Rick Miranda's algebraic curves and riemann surfaces but I couldn't manage to write a proof even after studying that book, which I did for my thesis.

definition of Γ: Let $m_1,...,m_r$ be positive integers with $m_i$ ≥ 2 for all i. The polygonal group of type m := $(m_1,...,m_r)$ is the group presented as follows: $Γ(m_1, . . . , m_r) = Γ(m) := <γ_1,...,γ_r | γ_1^{m_1}=...=γ_r^{m_r}=γ_1*...*γ_r=1>$.

**edit**
the "proof" i wrote:

$(\Rightarrow)$ $G\subseteq Aut(C) \Rightarrow$ $G$ acts holomorphically so the point $p\in C$ with non trivial stabilizer are finite.
Let $B=\{b_i\}$ be the images of such points via $\pi$.

Fix $b_i$ let $k$ be the cardinality of $\pi^{-1}(b_i)$, and for every $p\in \pi^{-1}(b_i)$ let $m_i:=mult_p(\pi)$.
There exist a punctured neighborhood $W$ of $b_i$ small enough s.t. for every $g_j\in G$ the action of $G$ over $W$ is (in local normal form) $z\to z^{k_j}$, $k_j|m_j$.
We can define $\theta:\Gamma\to G$ on the generators: $\theta(\gamma_i^{k_j})=g$, in particular: $<\theta(\gamma_i)>=G_p$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Select $r$ points $B:=\{b_i\}_{i=1,...,r}$ on $\mathbb P^1$ and $y_0\in\mathbb P^1-B$
We wanna "build" C compact Riemann surface s.t. $\pi:C\to\mathbb P^1$ is a branched covering.
for every $p\notin B:\;\;|\pi^{-1}(p)|=|G|$.
for every i: $|\pi^{-1}(b_i)|=\frac{|G|}{m_i}$ and let $W_i$ be a punctured neighborhood of $b_i$, $W_i\subset\mathbb P^1-B$.

$\gamma_i\in\Gamma$ acts on the points of $\pi^{-1}(\mathbb P^1-B)$ as $[\alpha]\in\pi_1(\mathbb P^1-B,y_0)$ where $\alpha$ is a small loop araound $b_i$. This identification between generators defines a map: [
$beta:\pi_1(\mathbb P^1-B,y_0)\to\Gamma$ sia poi:
\begin{align*}
    \phi:\;&\Gamma\to S_d 
           &\gamma_i\to\sigma
\end{align*}

s.t. $\sigma$ is product of $\frac{|G|}{m_i}$ cycles of legth $m_i$. Such a $\sigma$ who fixes an index is:
$\sigma^{m_i}=(\sigma_1,..,\sigma_{\frac{|G|}{m_i}})^{m_i}=(\sigma_1^{m_i},..,\sigma_{\frac{|G|}{m_i}}^{m_i})=id$
the composition:
$\rho:=\beta\circ\phi:\;\pi_1(\mathbb P^1-B,y_0)\to\mathbb P^1$
is the monodromy representation so it induces:
$F_{\rho}:U_{\rho}\to\mathbb P^1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Specifically, please add some additional context to the question: what is $\Gamma(m_1,\cdots,m_r)$? Where (exactly) is this result in the paper? What happened when you tried to follow the reference in the statement?

Comment: Is there a particular family of Riemann surfaces in that paper you’re looking to realize explicitly? If so, I may have some leads.

Comment: No @Arkady, I'm just trying to find a proof to this statement wich I couldn't find anywhere

Comment: Can you show that Corollary 4.10 of Miranda's book, section III.4 is equivalent to this formulation?

Comment: I could but I need an explicit proof

Comment: Okay..Miranda derives through corollary 4.10 through a series of lemmas. Are you able to follow the arguments there? Are there specific ones that you cannot follow? Which part are you stuck on? Without specific information, I am afraid we will be of limited use to you.

Comment: I try it difficult to translate the hypothesis of an admissible epimorphism to the monodromy representation, in particular the transitive image part.

Comment: @Arkady are you able to show the equivalence with corollary 4.10 in miranda's book?